# Update Model in DbContext using MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I posted my data like the following code is showing to my controller:

EmployeesController.cs

```
[Route("api/[controller]/update")]
[HttpPost]
public System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]List<Employees> list)
{
    using (var context = new EmployeesDbContext())
    {
        foreach (var emp in list)
        {
            Console.Write("MyLOG: " + emp.id + " : " + emp.name + "\n");
            SQLEmployeeData sqlData = new SQLEmployeeData(context);
            sqlData.Update(emp);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I defined in the controller the class **SQLEmployeeData** with a method for updating an database entry:

```
public class SQLEmployeeData
{
private EmployeesDbContext _context { get; set; }
    //...
    public void Update(Employees emp)
        {
            //_context.Update(emp).Where(emp.id); // PSEUDOCODE

            Console.Write("UPDATELOG: " 
+ _context.Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.id == emp.id).id + " - " 
+ _context.Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.id == emp.idID).name + "\n");

            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    //...
}
```

Now I would like to replace the pseudocode because "where" does not exist. The log shows me the correct data which I would like to replace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Attach` method to attach object to entity framework and to update it set its state to `EntityState.Modified` and after calling `SaveChanges` then EF will send update query to DB

```
public void Update(Employees emp)
{
    _context.Employees.Attach(emp);
    _context.Entry(emp).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

in this case you will only use one query for updating.
Or in your case you can reduce data sent even more by setting modified properties manually.

```
public void Update(Employees emp)
{
    _context.Employees.Attach(emp);
    _context.Entry(emp).Property(a => a.name).IsModified = true;
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I could solve my problem:

```
public void Update(Employees emp)
        {
            Employees update_emp = new Employees();

            update_emp = _context.Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.id == emp.id);
            _context.Employees.Update(update_emp);
            update_emp.id = emp.id;
            update_emp.name = emp.name;

            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Maybe there is a better way. Feel free to show us alternatives :-)